# customize google store locator

Tags: google-maps-api-3

i am using google store locator (http://storelocator.googlecode.com/git/examples/custom.html) for display sport events.

Now I want to customize the messages from google. 
I would like to hide the message "There are no stores in this area. However, stores closest to you are listed below." if there is no event in the zoomed area. And I want to put a link over the hole line in the panel to redirect to a specific url.

Are there any options to customize store locator to my wishes?

thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The source is available.  Download it and change it to do what you want.  Those messages are defined in [this file](http://storelocator.googlecode.com/git/js/panel.js).

Comment: Sorry, the text itself is located in the store_locator.compiled.js

Is there a uncompiled store_locator.js to change the onmouseover and onclick event?

Comment: You have to change the uncompiled version (that the link in my answer points to, the rest of the uncompiled files are in the same directory), then either use it uncompiled or compile it.

Comment: thanks, when using the uncompiled version, i have to inlcude common.js,
feature.js,
featureset.js,
panel.js,
static-datasource.js,
store.js,
view.js 
on my own in the html file?

Comment: Yes, or combine them all into one file.  But it will be easier to pull in updates to the original source (if there are any) if you keep them organized the same.